# Finding the limit of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I haven't touched series and sequences in a while and am rusty, so need some direction in finding the following:

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2 + k^2}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $\frac{k}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}$ and see that your sum is a Riemann sum on $[0,1]$ for the uniform partition.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2206368/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1446408/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/692149/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bn%5E2%20%2B%20k%5E2%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 4):

Use Riemann sum:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2 + k^2}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1 + \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx$$